# Rare scenario in DevOps - using jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have new to aws and jenkins. I have a scenario as below.

We have an aws AMI which has jenkins installed in it. The AMI is a Linux platform. We already have few jobs set in the AMI for code bases (PHP and Python) for Development and QA environment.

Now that we have a new framework in .net which is again a part of the same project done in PHP. These are windows services written in .net.

Right now the deployment are performed manually. We pull the code and build the code in the same machine. So we take care of stop/starting the services manually during this process on the Windows AMI dedicated for this testing. We would like to create a job (build and deploy) as we do for python and PHP.

1. The challenge is that we want to build the code on the Windows AMI and the jenkins in running on Linux AMI.
2. Is there a way to establish a connection between the AMI's running in different operating systems in  aws.
3. Should we install powershell in windows to have ssh access. In that case we can establish a connection from Linux AMI to Windows AMI and then execute a .bat to do the rest of activities.

** We are specifically asked not to install another jenkins in Windows system since we want to maintain all the jobs in a single place and single server.

Comment: Hello Varad Did the answer help or are you still looking for solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not actually a very rare scenario. Its not uncommon to have Jenkins running on Linux and also have the need to build and deploy windows applications using it.

Lucky for you Jenkins handles this quite easily using the concept of a master/slave architecture, where in your case the master node will be your primary Jenkins install running on Linux and you will setup one or more 'slave' instances running windows and the jenkins agent that allows the two to coordinate.

Its all explained here:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Comment: @e-j-brennan .I am trying this setup on a test environment in my local network. Thank you for the answer.